# MySql IFNULL function in query

Tags: mysql

i am using mysql `ifnull` in query, if the `id` is null then it should return `1` but it is not working, i think the syntax is good... what is the problem?

the query i am using is:

```
SELECT IFNULL(id,1) autoid FROM tb_orders
```

Comment: can you provide the table data??

Comment: table is empty, no record exist in table.

Comment: You're querying on empty table?

Comment: @user3300467: Great !

Comment: @JohnWoo i have used COALESCE(id,1) as wel, but the issue is not resolved.

Comment: @user3300467 empty table doesn't mean NULL values are contained !!!

Comment: @Dikesh yes i am querying ON empty TABLE, i need id 1 WHEN id IS empty/NULL in the table

Comment: @user3300467: It makes sense when there exists at least a record with id as null or empty. But when the table itself is empty, it is not going to work.

Comment: @Ravinder if i use SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),1) autoid FROM tb_orders on empty table then it gives me 1. i actualy need to get id 1 when there's no record in the table without using MAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try with `COALESCE` like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(id,1) autoid FROM tb_orders
```

Just to add after watching your comments, the above query is usefull only when  your table has records on it. Querying on emplty table is like trying to get icecream from the empty refrigerator! ;-)

Comment: ur query works when records exist in table. thanks, BUT if i use SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),1) autoid FROM tb_orders on empty table then it gives me 1 as icecream :-) ... i actualy require to get id 1 when there's no record in the table without using MAX.

Answer (score 0):

For handling empty table you need to check if number of rows returned is zero or not

```
SELECT case COUNT(*) when 0 then 1 else IFNULL(id,1) END as autoid 
FROM tb_orders
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo for Empty table**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c583b/28)

But in my opinion you should use other value than 1 for autoid when table is empty to differentiate between non empty table with NULL value and empty table.

```
SELECT case COUNT(*) when 0 then -1 else IFNULL(id,1) END as autoid 
FROM tb_orders
```